# How to trigger WooCommerce order complete email?

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I want to be able to trigger the WooCommerce order complete email at a different stage in the WooCommerce checkout process. So I've disabled WooCommerce order complete email from the backend and am now looking for a line of code that will trigger the email at the point that I want. I've done a bit of research and I've found how to *remove* the order complete email but not how to trigger it manually. Any tips?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try this

```
$mailer = WC()->mailer();
$mails = $mailer->get_emails();
if ( ! empty( $mails ) ) {
    foreach ( $mails as $mail ) {
        if ( $mail->id == 'customer_completed_order' ) {
           $mail->trigger( $order->id );
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Any way to ensure someone doesn't abuse it, i.e. if I throw that into a specific place on the thankyou page, is there anyway to not send an email every time a person refreshes the page?

Answer (score 8):

Rather than looping or reusing the same object as suggested by @Sumit.
You can initiate a new object and then call the trigger.

```
$email_oc = new WC_Email_Customer_Completed_Order();
$email_oc->trigger($order_id);
```

Comment: If this is a default WP order class then yes.. if it is custom it will be added using the woocommerce_email_classes filter, therefore the custom email class might just not be available on request.

Comment: @RamonFincken this is in [WooCommerce core](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-emails-class-wc-email-customer-completed-order.html)

Answer (score 1):

It can also be used like that;

```
WC()->mailer()->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Completed_Order']->trigger( $order_id );
```