# How do I hide the purchase note in the WooCommerce 'order completed' email?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, email

For every product in WooCommerce I can add a purchase note ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxonj.jpg)). This purchase note is displayed on all subsequent emails to the customer.  Via custom PHP, how can I hide the purchase note on one specific email--the 'order completed' email in my case.

Is there a WooCommerce provided hook I can use?  The main WooCommerce template governing this email is `customer-completed-order.php`.  But that doesn't allow me to hide *just* the purchase note for a particular item--it allows me to hide all of the details for all items.

Alternatively, is there a way with PHP to check which particular email I am currently rendering, e.g.

```
if ($wc_email_template == "order_completed") {
// Execute this code.
}
```

If I can do that, then my issue would be resolved.  The reason I say that is because there exists another WooCommerce email template, `email-order-items.php`.  In it, I can indeed hide the purchase note.  But this applies to *all* emails, which I don't want.  So in this template, if I can insert a conditional to check if the email in-question is the 'order completed' email, it would resolve my issue.

**Possible Solution?**

From this [previous post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/184637/how-to-trigger-woocommerce-order-complete-email), maybe I can use the following to check if the email is the 'order completed' email.

```
$mailer = WC()->mailer();
$mails = $mailer->get_emails();
foreach ( $mails as $mail ) {
     if ( $mail->id == 'customer_completed_order' ) {
           // Execute my desired code here.
        }
     }
}
```

Not sure if that would that work though.  This code snippet seems to check if the 'customer_completed_order' email exists.  But in my case, I'm trying to insert that code into the PHP template that *creates* that very same email--so it sounds like the 'customer_completed_order' email will not exist yet, meaning this check will always fail.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're correct about that code snippet only checking the for the availability of the email. But you can probably still make your alternative approach work: the WC_Email classes set $sending to true when they're in the process of sending. So you could check something like:

```
WC()->mailer()->emails["WC_Email_Customer_Completed_Order"]->sending
```

Comment: OK thanks for that.  That check does indeed do what I need it to do. I'm going to move forward with that, and consider this the answer.  Thanks!